# Windows aplication that lives only in the taskbar

Tags: c#, c++, windows, clipboard, system-tray

I'm new to windows programming (any win 32 API).
I want to create a windows application that listens to the clipborad all the time and reacts to keyboard shortcuts (for example you copy text from the ClipBoard and press Ctrl-F and something is done on the text in the clipboard).
I know how to make a window app in win32 and in C# (.NET) but it's a windowed application which has a window and appears in the window panel.
I want an pplication that will only be visible in the taskbar right part so you can close it (like most antivirus do) and keeps on running from start will it's closed.

Anyone got some code template, or can reffer me to a tutorial ? i don't mind if it's C\C+ or C#.

10x.

Comment: I think that part is called not taskbar, but tray... correct me if I am wrong

Comment: first of all writing thanks is not that difficult after all, if you find writing thanks difficult how will you type the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be another windows application in which the form's `ShowInTaskbar` property is set to false and you add a `NotifyIcon` component to put it into tray. Here is an article from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/trayiconmenu01.aspx). You can find many more on codeproject or on other programming related sites.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this](http://everything2.com/title/Win32+system+tray+icon) useful, although it's in C.
Or [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/tipstricks/article.php/c6933) in C#.